# How do I find the iframe on this page?

Tags: html, iframe

http://www.sandyscastles.net/mlsalt.html

I want to use this iframe on a new site (getting rid of this one). I inspect the element in Chrome... but can't get the iframe to work... I must not be looking at the right source.

Can someone write me a clear explanation of how to find this code?

Answer (score 0):

are you trying to replace iframe? 
This is the code your page have.

```
<frameset rows="116,*" cols="*" frameborder="NO" border="1" framespacing="0">
  <frame src="mls2.html" name="topframe" scrolling="NO" noresize="">
  <frame src="http://elko.fnismls.com/idx/idx.aspx?Mls=ELKO&amp;Subscriber=bfad323f-3818-41b4-a951-8e2700f75a33&amp;MLSSearch=1" name="body" scrolling="no" noresize="">
</frameset>
```

Comment: Yes.How do I replicate the iframe on a new site as html? Is it possible? Neither one of these work when inserted ...  
[link] (<frame src="http://elko.paragonrels.com/idx/SearchIDX.aspx?RMLS_SESSION_GUID=%7b3a95d379-309f-40f6-8781-dfdcd298ded7%7d&MLS=ELKO&SUBSCRIBER=bfad323f-3818-41b4-a951-8e2700f75a33&MLSSearch=1&featuredbyclass=0&class=1 & name="body" scrolling="no" noresize=""></iframe>)
or
[link] (<frame src="http://elko.fnismls.com/idx/idx.aspx?Mls=ELKO&amp;Subscriber=bfad323f-3818-41b4-a951-8e2700f75a33&amp;MLSSearch=1" name="body" scrolling="no" noresize=""></iframe>)